# Ember #each not displaying last item in model

Tags: json, ember.js

So I am using Ember's [#each](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/) throughout my application and I am not running into any problems. But I am now hitting an issue in which the last item in the array is not being output correctly.

```
<select id="services" size="10" class="services-list">
    {{#each sortedModel as |service index|}}
             <option {{action 'select' service}}>
                    {{service.physicalName}} {{index}}
             </option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

This will output 0-9 in the array but not the 11th item. Here is my JSON object in which I am returning as the sorted model.

```
[
{
    "physicalName": "service1",
    "logicalName": "service 1"
},
{
    "physicalName": "service2",
    "logicalName": "service 2"
},
{
    "physicalName": "service3",
    "logicalName": "service 3"
},
{
    "physicalName": "service5",
    "logicalName": "service 5"
},
{
    "physicalName": "service6",
    "logicalName": "service 6"
},
{
    "physicalName": "service7",
    "logicalName": "service 7"
},
{
    "physicalName": "service8",
    "logicalName": "service 8"
},
{
    "physicalName": "service9",
    "logicalName": "service 9"
},
{
    "physicalName": "service10",
    "logicalName": "service 10"
},
{
    "physicalName": "service11",
    "logicalName": "service 11"
},
{
    "physicalName": "service12",
    "logicalName": "service 12"
}
]
```

[image: model]

but here is what is showing up:

[image: select output]

Comment: Maybe it's because you set up the size to 10?
`<select id="services" size="10" class="services-list">`

Comment: HAHA wow sometimes all you need is an outside eye. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pavol mentioned above in the comments, I ignorantly set the select size to 10 hence the showing of only 10

changing

```
<select id="services" size="10" class="services-list">
```

to

```
<select id="services" size={{model.length}} class="services-list">
```

fixes the problem